# Android: движение элементов в GridView

Tags: android, gridview, java

Можно-ли как-то двигать элементы `GridView`, желательно не по сетке, а свободно по всему экрану?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вьюшки располагаются внутри ViewGroup согласно их `z-order` - грубо говоря, порядковому индексу.

Фактически перемещение `View` внутри `ViewGroup` управляется изменением его `z-order` - простейший пример `ViewGroup.bringChildToFront()` он устанавливает `z-order` в ноль.

В `GridView` перемещение возможно только по сетке - ну разве что можно чуть-чуть регулировать положение вьюшки заданием полей/паддингов.